# Highlight streets in OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, upload, highlight, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm working on a little project and I need to do the following:
It's an Android app and the user had to be able to highlight a street (or block, alternatively) and send that selection data to the main server. I'm wondering if this is possible, and how I can do it. Also, how can I store this information and show it on a private map?
Example: the user highlights the street on its map, sends a report to the server with that specific street, then the server updates the map with that report, showing this updated map to the other users.
I'm using OSMDroid.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will have trouble as osmdroid is using tiles not the raw OSM data so it has no real ideas where the streets are.

Comment: Then which app is recommended for this? GMaps?

Comment: osmdroid can be used in a solution. You will probably need to get the street data as KML or some vector format. That can turned into a path which can then be hit-tested against. The first step is getting a good source of street data. Google's public apis may be a good source for KML street data.